# VBA FORMULA NOT WORKING WITH A VARIABLE

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have a vba working perfectly with a constant `5` :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5]) * 5"
```

but when a change the `5` to a variable `VR` an error define object 1004 is returned :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5]) * VR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sallina  please try this may by helpful to you

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5] *" & VR & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the variable VR in the code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim VR As Long
    VR = 5   
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-5]) * " & VR    
End Sub
```

Assigning in the workbook:

If using a named range in the workbook called **`VR`** you would avoid the variable declarations and use something like:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-7]) * VR"
```